# Which Mesivta volumes contain appendixes?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, talmud-bavli, writing-printing

I’d like to compile a list of the various features found at the end of select Mesivta volumes. They usually provide extra help with Gemara study using fancy charts and the like.

Comment: I take it you mean excluding the standard appendices like ילקוט ביאורים? You’re specifically looking for ones that only appear in a single volume?

Answer (score 2):

- Rosh Hashana Vol. 1, pictures regarding astronomy.
- Megillah Vol. 1, chart of 70 year diaspora and Megillah timeline chart
- Yevamos Vol. 1-6, charts of relationships.